# Failed to decode json in Swagger UI

Tags: python, flask, swagger-ui

I am writing a small api and testing it in Swagger UI. I need to add a json file as a parameter in Swagger. Here is code of my function:

```py
@APP.post('/get_query_by_id')
def create_new_query():
    """Make queries to database
    ---
    post:
      summary: Creates a new query
      tags: ["Queries"]
      consumes:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - in: body
          name: query
          description: New cypher query and description to create
          schema:
            type: object
            required:
              - userName
            properties:
              query:
                type: string
              description:
                type: string
      responses:
        201:
          description: OK
    """
    json_file = request.get_json(force=True)
```

The problem is that when the script passes the line `json_file = request.get_json(force=True)` it breaks with an error: `Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`.

This is what my Swagger docs look like:

[image: image of swagger docs]

Comment: are you actually posting JSON data to the endpoint?

Comment: I am using Swagger to test with this end point